# Ambiguity between potential causative and passive causative

Tags: grammar, conjugations, passive-voice, causation, potential-form

I have this thought from time to time when I am trying to express an English thought in Japanese. Perhaps the sentence itself is unnatural so let me know.

It seems like we can make him come (to a place far from the speaker. in a playful "forcing someone" way)

あ、行かせられそう

Does this work? I suppose 行ってもらえそう might work here but I thought it might be too soft for the nuance I want. And I know the actual passive causative would be 行かされる, but is it still possible these could get confused for each other? Does 行かせられる　sound like can make someone go? What about る-verb where the conjugation would look the same like 見させられる (can make him look or being forced to watch)

Comment: Looking at the English all I can see is 行かせそう where does the られ come from? (I assume you meant "make him **go** _somewhere_")

Comment: Yes thats what I meant. I mean different from just 行かせそう, more like できそう, so a combination of the potential and mas-stem +　そう

Answer (score 3, accepted):

行か**せられる** works for you, while 行か**される** doesn’t.

行かせる and 行かす are both valid causative forms of 行く.

The former works as a ru-verb (or *ichidan* or Group II verb), and therefore, its potential and passive forms are both 行か**せられる**. As with any other ru-verb, ambiguity could arise. Depending on the context, it could mean either “can make someone go” or “be forced to go.”

The latter, the short form, works as an u-verb (or *godan* or Group I verb), and therefore, its potential form would be 行か**せる**. However, this form is usually not used because it is identical to the (long) causative form. You would need to say 行かすことができる to mean “can make someone go.” 行か**される** only means “be forced to go.”

見る is not a very good example because there is another verb with a causative sense, namely 見せる.

Let’s use 食べる as an example of a ru-verb.

Its causative form is 食べさせる and this also works as a ru-verb. Therefore, its potential and passive forms are both 食べ**させられる**. Depending on the context, it could mean either “can make someone eat” or “be forced to eat.”